# d3 directed graph with varying stroke-widths

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout, directed-graph

I'm trying to make a simple directed graph using d3.
I have the basic graph up and running referring to the examples http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 , http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5155181 and http://bl.ocks.org/dustinlarimer/5888271

The issue I'm facing is that for my use case, I need to have different widths for the edges based on the specified weight of the edge. Now when I try to change the "stroke-width" property, the widths of the arrow markers also becomes very large (attaching a screenshot)[image].

I would be really thankful if someone could point to a specific example or offer suggestions for a quick workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the marker the `markerUnits` attribute with `userSpaceOnUse` value, which overrides that default sizing behavior:

```
.attr('markerUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
```